# How to mock restTemplate.postForEntity using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have this in my service:

```java
    private String postMethod(List<Integer> list) {
        String url = ...

        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, list, String.class);
        return result.getBody();
    }
```

In my test class I try to mock it like this:

```java
    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void methodTest() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(22234,9842234));
        when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<String>("5be9b7f2b7c", HttpStatus.OK));
        String result = enrollmentServiceClient.retry(list);

        assertEquals("5be9b7f2b7c", result);
    }
```

When I run my test I get a null pointer exception. Does anyone know why it is not returning the ResponseEntity?

Looks like this is the method I should be mocking:

public  ResponseEntity postForEntity(URI url, @Nullable Object request, Class responseType)

Comment: Where are you getting the null pointer from? Is your restTemplate showing as null?

Comment: yes. restTemplate is showing null

Comment: show your class definition.

Answer (score 1):

1. Test must be annotated with [@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.html). This annotation automatically initializes mocks annotated with `@Mock`. In case you have used JUnit 5 you must use [@ExtendWith({MockitoExtension.class})](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/4.6.1/org/mockito/junit/jupiter/MockitoExtension.html) instead.
2. `RestTemplate` mock should be injected into the service under the test. You need to create a constructor for `EnrollmentServiceClient` service with `RestTemplate` parameter. `RestTemplate` mock can be injected into service via [@InjectMocks](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) annotation

Example of working test:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestClass {
    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    EnrollmentServiceClient enrollmentServiceClient;

    @Test
    public void methodTest() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(22234,9842234));
        when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<String>("RESULT", HttpStatus.OK));
        String result = enrollmentServiceClient.retry(list);

        assertEquals("RESULT", result);
    }
}

public class EnrollmentServiceClient {
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public EnrollmentServiceClient(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    private String postMethod(List<Integer> list) {
        String url = "...";
        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, list, String.class);
        return result.getBody();
    }

    public String retry(List<Integer> list) {
        return postMethod(list);
    }
}
```